# C++ - vector of futures

Tags: c++, future

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class Calculator {
public:
    static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::future<int>*> futures;

    for(auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        auto future = new std::async(&Calculator::add, 1, 3);
        futures.push_back(future);
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << futures[i]->get() << std::endl;
        delete futures[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no type named 'async' in namespace 'std'
```

How do I store and call get() on a vector of futures?

Update:

I am using C++ 11 and an async example without the vector logic works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being *deeply* suspicious of any code using naked `new` or `delete` calls (a good attitude to develop, by the way), I rewrote it to use more 'modern' C++ idioms.

I wasn't *entirely* sure why you thought you needed to store *pointers* to futures, that seemed to complicate matters unnecessarily. In any case, the snippet `new std::async()` caused problems for `g++`and I believe this is the cause of your error `no type named 'async' in namespace 'std'`.

Technically, this is correct, there is no *type* `async` in `std`, because`async` is a *function* rather than a type.

The modified code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class Calculator {
public:
    static int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
    for(auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        futures.push_back(std::async(&Calculator::add, i, 3));
    for(auto i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << futures[i].get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine, giving the results I would expect to see:

```
pax> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pthread -std=c++11 -o testprog testprog.cpp
pax> ./testprog
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: why are you suspicious of new and delete?

Comment: @solarflare: because, with smart pointers, they're almost never necessary. They're still okay provided you know in great detail about their lifetime and ownership, but smart pointers are almost *always* better if there's any doubt.